# Haskell type Error in expression using $ operator

Tags: haskell

I've been working through "Haskell Programming from first principles" by Christopher Allen
and Julie Moronuki, and am stuck on a code sample on page 55 which does not seem to function.

The sample is to illustrate the use of the $ operator with the following expression run in GHCI:

```
(2^) $ (*30) $ 2 + 2
```

This causes the following error to be raised

```
<interactive>:146:1: error:
• Could not deduce (Num t10)
  from the context: (Num a, Num t1, Num (t1 -> a))
    bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
               forall {a} {t1}. (Num a, Num t1, Num (t1 -> a)) => a
    at <interactive>:146:1-20
  The type variable ‘t10’ is ambiguous
  Potentially matching instances:
    instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
    instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    ...plus three others
    ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall {a} {t1}. (Num a, Num t1, Num (t1 -> a)) => a
```

Have I made some kind of error in entering the expression? Should this be a valid expression in Haskell? What does the error given actually mean?

EDIT: I restarted GHCI and the expression above now evaluates without error, giving the expected value. Now I'm unable to reproduce the error.

EDIT2: I wondered if I could have accidentally redefined something earlier in the GHCI session. Reading from the book I think I might have erroneously entered the following (which looked like it was a code sample):

```
f $ a = f a
```

Now I'm able to reproduce the issue as above. Still not sure whats going on though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. The expression is accepted by my GHCi installation (v 8.10.7).

Comment: I have Stack GHCI installed via Homebrew. The start up preamble gives me - "GHCi, version 9.4.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help"

Comment: Works fine here (GHC 9.2.7). Try closing and reopening your GHCi, without loading any module. The error mentioning `Num (t1 -> a)` is fishy, and makes me wondering if you entered that line exactly or if you redefined something in a module (or via the GHCi prompt).

Comment: Can't reproduce as well with GHC v8.8.4 or v9.0.1

Comment: Well, I am very confused. I just restarted GHCI and ran it again, and it works. Returning the expected value. Genuinely no idea what had happened there. I was stuck for hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: See my second edit. I think I managed to mess up my GHCI session somehow, but I'm not sure exactly what I did.

Comment: So you were working with your own local version of ($), which apparently got a different precedence level from the library-provided one.

Comment: I guess. It wasn't clear to me that I had redefined anything. Or that that could even be done for language constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GHCi, version 9.8.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :info $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b       -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 0 $
ghci> f $ a = f a
ghci> :info $
($) :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2   -- Defined at <interactive>:2:3
infixl 9 $
ghci>
```

As you can see from the above, the fixity of `GHC.Base`'s definition of `$` is `infixr 0`, but the fixity of yours is `infixl 9` (the default, since you didn't specify one). As a result, the expression `(2^) $ (*30) $ 2 + 2` was being parsed as `(((2^) $ (*30)) $ 2) + 2`, which means the nonsensical
`(2^) (*30) 2 + 2`, when it should have been parsed as `(2^) $ ((*30) $ (2 + 2))`, which means the correct `(2^) ((*30) (2 + 2))`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I accidentally entered "f $ a = f a" what did that do? It doesn't look like a valid expression to me.

Comment: @Jon it's not an expression, that's a function definition; the syntax is equivalent to `($) f a = f a`. You could also have used a different operator here, like `f #+# f = f a`, then you could write something like `(+1) #+# 10`. In Haskell, operator symbols are valid for function names, and by default they'll allow infix function calls.

Comment: @Cubic okay. I'm tripping over terminology in that case. I thought a function definition was an expression. Clearly not. How does `f $ a = f a` get parsed as a function called "$"? Surely it should get parsed as a function called `f`?

Comment: @Jon there's no deep reason or anything. That's just how the parsing rules work when operators are used, operators on the LHS of a definition don't behave any differently than on the RHS. So you can write `x + y = x * y` if you want to redefine `+` to mean "multiply two numbers" (not that you should).

You can even use the backtick syntax, e.g. `x \`f\` y = x + y`, `f 10 2 == 12`